# Manipulate saved object after ngResource $save

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to $save an object and empty it's values after.

I've got:

```
$scope.newObject = new ObjectService()

$scope.saveObject = function(objectToSave)
```

so `ng-click="saveObject(newObject)` calls the function passes the object and then I'm trying to empty it's values after $save is done. The way I want to do it is initialise the `objectToSave` into a `new ObjectService()` again (as it was before $save()). The problem is that it just doesn't work (I know this probably has to do with Javascript fundamentals, I just don't know what it is).

**Please check the code snippet bellow. The code comments explain my issue better.**

**Please note !** *: I'm trying to handle the response of $save in .error() function because this is an example.*

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'ObjectService',
    function($scope, ObjectService) {
      $scope.newObject = new ObjectService();
      $scope.newObject.foo = 'something';

      $scope.saveObject = function(object) {
        object.$save(function() {
          // won't success in this example..
        }, function() {
          //object.foo = '...'; // This works fine.
          object = new ObjectService();
          // $scope.newObject shouldn't be a new ObjectService now? So $scope.newObject.foo should be an empty string

        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .factory('ObjectService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      return $resource('http://somewhere/something', {
        foo: '@foo'
      });
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newObject.foo">
  <button type="button" ng-click="saveObject(newObject)">Save</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object = new ObjectService();

Won't work because the way that arguments are passed to functions in Javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

In your case, you can assign to $scope.newObject a new empty object.

$scope.newObject = new ObjectService();

You don't even need the argument because you can use the variable $scope.newObject to call resource methods.